# Convert string array to array for Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I've got a front-end web application with a HTML5 input that allows a user to input some kind of condition, which is posted into a function within my Laravel project to run inside of the `where` clause.

It works just fine if I manually take my array of conditions and paste it inside of my clause, but doesn't work when posted since it's a string.

Trying to figure out whether it's a simple case of casting the string to an array to get it to work?

```php
/**
 * Find data based on discovery of sources
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 */
public function findDataFromSources(Request $request)
{

    $request_data = $request->all();
    $realData = [
      'size' => 0,
      'results' => []
    ];

    // try and return the data
    try {

      foreach ($request_data as $key => $findable) {
        $res = DB::table($findable['table'])
                 ->select($findable['columns'])
                 ->where($findable['filterBy']) // cast this to array maybe? 
                 ->take(10)
                 ->get();

        $realData['size'] += count($res);
        array_push($realData['results'], $res);
      }

      $data = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Your chosen data sources and fields',
        'sources' => $realData
      ];

      // Yay!
      return response()->json($data, 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      // Something went wrong
      return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => $e], 422);

    }

}
```

`filterBy` comes in as a String like so:

```
{
  filterBy: "[['column', '=', 'value']]"
}
```

Comment: That looks like almost JSON. Real JSON would be using double quotes. Are you certain this is literally the value, with single quotes?

Comment: Thanks for that, got it now